# Specifying prior recipe using PREFERRED_VERSION doesn't work in Yocto bitbake?

Tags: yocto, recipe

I'm working on Yocto bitbake.
I found that once can specify the recipe using `PREFERRED_VERSION` directive in `conf/local.conf`, if there are multiple recipes for the same component.

I'm using "Rocko", and want to select version "1.1.0" of openssl so I appended the line below to `conf/local.conf`.

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_openssl = "1.1.%"
```

But, it looks that it doesn't work and `openssl-1.0.2` was built.
Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_openssl_forcevariable = "1.1.%"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I made it by this way.